# Make unique DWord constants, not concurrent to any TObject address

Tags: delphi

I use Python4Delphi in D7. I want to pass object address as "handle" to Py part. E.g.
`h:= Integer(Pointer(Memo1));`. I also want to have special handle values, which mean some specials objects, e.g. `-1` means "current memo", `-2` means "next memo".

How can I choose such few (I need 5) constants, which won't conflict with object adresses?
E.g.

- `-1` - can it be address of some TMemo (of other TObject)?
- `-2` - can it be address of some TMemo?
- what else constants can I take which cannot be TMemo addresses?

Comment: In Win32, the first 64KB of address space is permanently invalid.

Comment: [David's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21615291/224704) is the way to go. In addition I'd like to point out: Negative numbers _could_ work as sentinels if the app isn't compiled with LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE enabled. **Howver**, I strongly advise **against** this approach, because it effectively prevents you from using that option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly on Windows, you can use low addresses for this purpose. You need five sentinel values? Use 1 to 5. Those values are never valid addresses in user space.

Of course, if you are prepared to allocate the values at runtime, you can reserve some addresses for yourself with a simple call to `GetMem`. Again, you need five addresses, call `GetMem(5)` and you are done.

Comment: Thakx again for help, David